# What is the best way to center an equation and flush right another equation on the same line?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, center

I want to have an equation with a main formula centered and a parameter in parenthesis flushed to the right. I have tried some things but none of them have worked.

Comment: If you will show what you try so far, this will help us to help you. Is your equation numbered?

Comment: They do not work, so there are of no use. If someone does know what works, they will respond. My equation is numbered on the left in amsart.

Comment: Did you try with the `flalign` environment?

Comment: No, how could I use this?

Comment: It is an amsmath environment, wg=hci defines three alignment columns: the first is flushledt, the second is centred and the last is flushright. You might try to use it with an empty left column

Comment: Where do I use wg=hci?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, and I forgot to reread my comment. I meant   `which defines`.  Take a look at the amsmath documentation, you'll how it works.

Comment: When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If I've guessed what you wanted, it must look like that :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\author{M.BAUD}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{flalign}
&\square    &\begin{aligned}[t]y+y&=x-y\\
                                  &=\ldots\\
                                  &=\ldots
             \end{aligned}
&   &\text{parameters}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It uses the mentioned `flalign` env.

Comment: I tried this, but for my longer equations, they were shifted too far to the left.